# Why the certificate is rejected despite it being installed?

Tags: certificate

When accessing a URL in my LAN using the web browser, I get a certificate error message:

In Firefox:

```
Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead
```

In Internet Explorer:

```
This site is not secure
```

I download the certificate and import it using Windows Powershell as admin:

```
> certutil -addstore -enterprise -f "Root" .\certificate.pem
Root "Trusted Root Certification Authorities"
Signature matches Public Key
Certificate "Certificate" added to store.
CertUtil: -addstore command completed successfully.
```

The issue isn't solved.

If I ping to the IP address, I get a response. However, if I telnet to the IP:port using Putty, I get a pop-up window with the following error message:

```
Remote side unexpectedly closed network connection
```

How can I get my computer to accept the certificate?